# Firebase how to handle linkWithCredential "ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE" in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

OK here is the error I get:

1- When the app starts with phone1, user sign In Anonymously. Uid:ABC ([link1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously))

2- phone1 user decides to login with Google Sign-In. User already has an Uid:ABC, so that User is converted from anonymous account to a permanent account with google sign-in. ([link2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account))

3- With phone2, the app is launched first time and sign in Anonymously. Uid:ZYX ([link1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously))

4- With phone2, user wants to login with same google account. So at this point using linkWithCredential cause "ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE". ([link2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account))

So what is the proper solution for this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to ***link*** **Two UIDs with Same Auth Credentials** i.e with same google account. Which in itself is major security flaw and something that should never be done in a production app.

According to firebase official docs

> **ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE** when trying to *link a user* with an
>   AuthCredential corresponding to *another account* already in use

You should rather **try to simply Sign - In** and it will work. Your **current action is equivalent to Sign - Up.**

Please refer to [these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) docs for proper google sign-in implementation. For your above procedure to work. **You will first have to delete previous user** so that *old UID linked to the gmail account get's deleted*.

Do let me know if this info helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've just tried simply sign-in like the info you wrote above. It works! :)

Comment: @MiloRambaldi am glad it did. Good Luck :)